# How to insert images in columns without text around and still keeping them in textwidth

Tags: graphics, positioning, multicolumn, multicol

I am writing a book for my master's degree and currently I can not find a way to put a image on the top of a column. I tried several methods that were here and none fixed my problem.

So, I have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con-sectetuer adipiscing elit.   Ut puruselit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adip-iscing vitae, felis.  Curabitur dictumgravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, non-ummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputatea, magna.  Donec vehicula augue euneque.  Pellentesque habitant morbitristique senectus et netus et male-suada fames ac turpis egestas.  Mau-ris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncussem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urnafringilla ultrices.  Phasellus eu tellussit amet tortor gravida placerat. Inte-ger sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis,viverra ac, nunc.  Praesent eget semvel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean fau-cibus.  Morbi dolor nulla, malesuadaeu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla.   Donecvarius orci eget risus.  Duis nibh mi,congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittisquis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orcidignissim rutrum.Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismodsodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.  Morbiauctor lorem non justo.  Nam lacuslibero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ul-tricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortorsed accumsan bibendum, erat ligulaaliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metusa mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendreritmollis.  Suspendisse ut massa.  Crasnec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cumsociis natoque penatibus et magnis disparturient montes, nascetur ridiculusmus. \ref{Image} Aliquam tincidunt urna.  Nullaullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellen-tesque cursus luctus mauris.Nulla malesuada porttitor diam.Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpatat, tincidunt tristique, libero.  Viva-mus viverra fermentum felis.
\end{multicols}{2}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{void.jpg}
\centering
\caption{Image}
\centering
\label{Image}
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}
Donecnonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellusadipiscing semper elit. Proin fermen-tum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis,molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec,leo. Maecenas lacinia.  Nam ipsumligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, sus-cipit a, ipsum.  Morbi blandit ligulafeugiat magna.  Nunc eleifend conse-quat lorem.  Sed lacinia nulla vitaeenim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus velmagna.  Integer non enim.  Praesenteuismod nunc eu purus. Donec biben-dum quam in tellus.  Nullam cursuspulvinar lectus.  Donec et mi.  Namvulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulumpellentesque felis eu massa.Quisque ullamcorper placerat ip-sum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitaelacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscingelit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiamfacilisis. Nunc elementum fermentumwisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet,enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odioplacerat quam, ac pulvinar elit puruseget enim.  Nunc vitae tortor.  Prointempus nibh sit amet nisl.  Vivamusquis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula.Fusce mauris.  Vestibulum luctusnibh at lectus.  Sed bibendum, nullaa faucibus semper, leo velit ultriciestellus, ac venenatis arcu wisi vel nisl.Vestibulum diam. 
\end{multicols}{2}
\end{document}
```

And this appears to me like this:
[image: This image is from the code that have the endmulticols.]

Then, I tried other options that was to put `\begin{figure*}` and this did not help either. Adding the extra symbol made all the other images that were in the same chapter go to the bottom, even after the bibliography.

I also tried the next option that I found, hoping to work. But it did not. It went like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...  Viva-mus viverra fermentum felis.
\multicolfloat{1}{2}{\centering
    \includegraphics{void.jpg}
    \captionof{figure}{A test}
    }
Donecnonummy pellentesque ante...Vestibulum diam. 
\end{multicols}{2}
\end{document}
```

This was the result:
[image: This image is from the code that have multicols]

One option that made to the column was the one that wrapped the text to the image, but this is not my final desired format. It went exactly like the example of the Overleaf website. My intention is having something similar to this book example.

Overleaf website example:
[image: Overleaf website example]

Book example:
[image: Book example]

Now, I am short of options and being new to this is not making my life easier. Please, if you have any suggestions that I can try I am willing to. I am using Overleaf if it makes any difference.

Edit: I am looking for the result similar to the book example regarding to image in text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Sorry if this was a silly question or wasn't clear. It was my first post, so not sure how to use this properly. The solution for my case was:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con-sectetuer adipiscing elit.   Ut puruselit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adip-iscing vitae, felis.  Curabitur dictumgravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, non-ummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputatea, magna.  Donec vehicula augue euneque.  Pellentesque habitant morbitristique senectus et netus et male-suada fames ac turpis egestas.  Mau-ris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncussem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urnafringilla ultrices.  Phasellus eu tellussit amet tortor gravida placerat. Inte-ger sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis,viverra ac, nunc.  Praesent eget semvel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean fau-cibus.  Morbi dolor nulla, malesuadaeu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla.   Donecvarius orci eget risus.  Duis nibh mi,congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittisquis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orcidignissim rutrum.Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismodsodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.  Morbiauctor lorem non justo.  Nam lacuslibero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ul-tricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortorsed accumsan bibendum, erat ligulaaliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metusa mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendreritmollis.  Suspendisse ut massa.  Crasnec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cumsociis natoque penatibus et magnis disparturient montes, nascetur ridiculusmus. Aliquam tincidunt urna.  Nullaullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellen-tesque cursus luctus mauris.Nulla malesuada porttitor diam.Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpatat, tincidunt tristique, libero.  Viva-mus viverra fermentum felis.

    \includegraphics{void.jpg}
    \captionof{figure}{A test}
    
Donecnonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellusadipiscing semper elit. Proin fermen-tum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis,molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec,leo. Maecenas lacinia.  Nam ipsumligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, sus-cipit a, ipsum.  Morbi blandit ligulafeugiat magna.  Nunc eleifend conse-quat lorem.  Sed lacinia nulla vitaeenim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus velmagna.  Integer non enim.  Praesenteuismod nunc eu purus. Donec biben-dum quam in tellus.  Nullam cursuspulvinar lectus.  Donec et mi.  Namvulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulumpellentesque felis eu massa.Quisque ullamcorper placerat ip-sum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitaelacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscingelit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiamfacilisis. Nunc elementum fermentumwisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet,enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odioplacerat quam, ac pulvinar elit puruseget enim.  Nunc vitae tortor.  Prointempus nibh sit amet nisl.  Vivamusquis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula.Fusce mauris.  Vestibulum luctusnibh at lectus.  Sed bibendum, nullaa faucibus semper, leo velit ultriciestellus, ac venenatis arcu wisi vel nisl.Vestibulum diam. 
\end{multicols}{2}
\end{document}
```

This was my intention:
[image: Image provided from autor]

The `\includegraphics{void.jpg}\captionof{figure}{A test}` is possible to be used in any part of the multicols, however, some editing in the size of the image may be required to fit better.

Comment: From your question doesn't follows that your answer fulfil requirements posted in question. Now, as it can be seen, only you know, what  you after. To not insert image in float `figure` cause empty space in the bottom of the first first column.  ​How big it will be you in the case when image has height about half of text height?  Quite ugly result ... You should made your question more clear in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, it is my first time posting something here. I am not sure if you saw the example of the book in the post. I managed to break the text and page if something is not in place. My "Ugly result" worked for me while your previous reply didn't. It is a shame that you deleted your answer...

Comment: Why is shame to delete my answer if it is not of any help to anybody? About ugly result: it can happen if you not inserts images or tables in float environments. I just warn you about possible consequence. Happy TeXing!

Comment: It was a shame because had a link that helped me to understand better how to use images. Just because it wasn't what I needed here, doesn't mean that is not useful. Thank you.

Comment: You still can delete my name from your answer. Please, do so, because I newer suggest a solution, which can lead to unexpected problems or to my opinion to "ugly" result. BTW, it was not nice from you that you rather write own answer as make your question more clear and by this make my answer superfluous (so I delete it). Anyway, . I will not argue with you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I wrote an answer for my own question because I managed to do it, not to make my question more clear. It was never my intention to write an answer to make others look like they don't help. Be nicer with the people that are starting to use this platform and if you really want to help, explain instead of just deleting stuff that doesn't give you upvotes. Have a happy life : )